# scala java scala/App error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala

I am new to both Java and Scala. I have created the jar file and wants it to be executed on JVM. I am not sure what is the problem here. Kindly help me. Please find the error log and command called

```
My-mini:~ DC$ export JVM_ARGS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=512M -  XX:MaxPermSize=1024M"
My-mini:~ DC$ java $JVM_ARGS -jar /Users/DC/Desktop/eclipse/Workspace/FTDataProject/target/scala-2.11/ftdataproject_2.11-1.0.jar MainApp.scala Germany 20140728
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/App
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.DC.FTDataParser.MainApp.main(MainApp.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.App
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: The most common cause (of among a dozen or more) for NCDFE is having mismatched JAR files -- either two JARs that are incompatible, or compiling with one set of JARs and running with a different, incompatible set.

Comment: Normally, use `scala` to run the code; it puts scala jars on the classpath for you.  Eclipse also runs scala apps.  Also, running as "script" (foo.scala) is different from running compiled code (foo.class).